# pallets are getting stuck at top left corner in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am a beginner in android studio I did only one project which it worked properly but after that project
when I place any pallet it moves at top left corner, I even tried in relative layout but it also did not work. Please give me suggestion on my problem.

Comment: What's a pallet? I'm confused on whether this is a question about the IDE tool windows or an XML layout...

Answer (score 0):

in constraint layout you need to give it constraints. And in Relative layout you need to give margins to set at the desired position.